# Memory leaks with "weak" and "strong" attributes

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, instruments

Using LRResty for all api calls on one of the project I work on. I have noticed the project leaks memory a lot, so I have been given work to fix all the leakage and improve stability of the current application.

***The following is the scenario:***
The entire project is under ARC, but LRResty is non-arc.
View controller initialises "CustomService" object that passes self as delegate.
CustomService object calls LRResty client that handles the request and returns response.
CustomService has private property request with attribute "weak".

***The problem is:***
When I run instruments (either on iphone or simulator) the leaks are detected, in both cases where property request attribute is "weak" and "strong". The request (LRRestyRequest) is weak (in this case customService dealloc gets called) otherwise customService gets caught in retain cycle and dealloc will not be called. With attribute "weak" the leak is "malloc" and I can't identify the source, however if I change attribute to "strong" the "Instruments" shows me leaks at initWithDelegate:self and [customService serviceScheduleRequest], and dealloc of customService is never called.

How can I make this code leak free? I spent hours and I have no clue. Is it possible that LRResty framework is in charge of that memory issue? Anyone has experience with working with this framework?

**MyViewController**

```
CustomService *customService = [[CustomService alloc] initWithDelegate:self]; 
[customService serviceScheduleRequest];
```

**CustomService.h**

```
@protocol CustomServiceDelegate;

@interface CustomService : Service <LRRestyClientResponseDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<CustomServiceDelegate> delegate;

- (id) initWithDelegate:(id)aDelegate;
- (void)serviceScheduleRequest;

@end

@protocol CustomServiceDelegate <NSObject>

@optional

- (void) serviceScheduleRequestDidStart;
- (void) serviceScheduleRequestDidEndWithSuccessJSON:(id) JSON;
- (void) serviceScheduleRequestDidEndWithSuccess:(BOOL) status;
- (void) serviceScheduleRequestDidEndWithError:(NSError *)error;

@end
```

**CustomService.m**

```
@interface CustomService ()

@property (nonatomic, weak) LRRestyRequest *request;

@end

@implementation CustomService

@synthesize delegate=_delegate;

- (id) initWithDelegate:(id)aDelegate
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        _delegate = aDelegate;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)serviceScheduleRequest
{
    NSMutableDictionary* parameters = [self getParams];

    self.private_request = [[LRResty client] post:@"http://mylink.com/apicall"
                                  payload:parameters
                                 delegate:self];
}


- (NSMutableDictionary*) getParams
{
    NSMutableDictionary* parameters = [super getParams];
    return parameters;
}


- (void)restClient:(LRRestyClient *)client receivedResponse:(LRRestyResponse *)response
{   
    [self.delegate callSomeMethod];
    // do something...
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"\n\n\n\n dealloc gets called \n\n\n\n");
}

@end
```

**Stack trace** just in case if it gives anyone clue

```
0 libsystem_c.dylib realloc
1 Foundation _NSMutableDataGrowBytes
2 Foundation -[NSConcreteMutableData appendBytes:length:]
3 Foundation -[NSConcreteMutableData appendData:]
4 MyApp -[LRURLRequestOperation connection:didReceiveData:] /Users/admin/.jenkins/jobs/LRResty Nightly Builds/workspace/Classes/LRURLRequestOperation.m:107
5 MyApp -[LRRestyRequest connection:didReceiveData:] /Users/admin/.jenkins/jobs/LRResty Nightly Builds/workspace/Classes/LRRestyRequest.m:177
6 Foundation ___NSURLConnectionDidReceiveData_block_invoke_0
7 Foundation __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke_0
8 Foundation -[NSURLConnectionInternalConnection invokeForDelegate:]
9 Foundation -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]
10 Foundation -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:]
11 Foundation _NSURLConnectionDidReceiveData
12 CFNetwork ___delegate_cacheTrifecta_block_invoke_0
13 CFNetwork ___withDelegateAsync_block_invoke_0
14 CFNetwork ___performAsync_block_invoke_068
15 CoreFoundation CFArrayApplyFunction
16 CFNetwork RunloopBlockContext::perform()
17 CFNetwork non-virtual thunk to RunloopBlockContext::multiplexerClientPerform()
18 CFNetwork MultiplexerSource::perform()
19 CoreFoundation __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
20 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopDoSources0
21 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopRun
22 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunSpecific
23 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunInMode
24 Foundation -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:]
25 Foundation -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run]
26 MyApp -[LRURLRequestOperation start] /Users/admin/.jenkins/jobs/LRResty Nightly Builds/workspace/Classes/LRURLRequestOperation.m:63
27 MyApp -[LRRestyRequest start] /Users/admin/.jenkins/jobs/LRResty Nightly Builds/workspace/Classes/LRRestyRequest.m:136
28 Foundation __block_global_6
29 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_call_block_and_release
30 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_client_callout
31 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_root_queue_drain
32 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_worker_thread2
33 libsystem_c.dylib _pthread_wqthread
34 libsystem_c.dylib start_wqthread
```

Comment: The `weak` attribute is correct, otherwise you'll end up in a retain loop. You should be able to see the stack trace of leaked memory for `malloc`.

Comment: Ok, in this case, if LRResty is non-ARC and and is referenced as weak property (so in this case its retain count doesn't get increased) in ARC object then when the customService object is dealloc the LRResty object is not freed and the leak is going to happen. How to overcome this, as I think this is the reason of my problem.

Comment: `LRRestyRequest` is an autoreleased object and you don't own a reference to it, so there is nothing you can do with it. But someone has left another reference that's preventing it from being released. Add a breakpoint in `-[LRRestyRequest dealloc]` and `-[LRURLRequestOperation dealloc]`.

Comment: Can't place breakpoints as it is implemented as compiled static framework :(

Comment: Perhaps you should build from source